# photoswipe fullscreen button missing on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, photoswipe

Using this link: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-perfect-lightbox-using-photoswipe-with-jquery--cms-23587 i have been able to insert photoswipe into my website.

Unfortunately i cant get the fullscreen button visible on mobile devices, the demo website does show the fullscreen button.

Comparison:

- http://photoswipe.com/
- http://ezg.agaastra.nl/Korpsgeschiedenis

(In my site: click bottom pictures)

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I have searched whole internet for a solution but havent found it yet.

Comment: Which device? On an iPhone, the Photoswipe.com demo does not show any fullscreen button either, which is normal as iOS Safari doesn't support it.

Comment: I tried using stock browser for android (4.4.4), demo from photoswipe doesn't show fullscreen button either.

Comment: for andraid 5+ it worked fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 58 of http://ezg.agaastra.nl/Content/photoswipe-theme.css, the button elements are formatted with

```
background-image: url(default-skin.svg)
```

for mobile – but that image does not exist on your server, `http://ezg.agaastra.nl/Content/default-skin.svg` only results in a 404.

Therefor, the background image those buttons would have on desktop is overwritten, but no new background image is available to display – and therefor you see just “nothing”.

So see to it that you upload that missing image to the correct location.

Comment: I can confirm this answer.  Had the same problem and it turned out to be the file: default-skin.svg.
Copy that file into the folder where the other default-skin files are and voila!